# VBA code does not return the row of a button correctly

Tags: vba, excel

The following code creates buttons dynamically in my spreadsheet

```
Sub CreateButton(ButtonName As String, Rng As Range, Macro As String)
    ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(Rng.Left, Rng.Top, Rng.Width, Rng.Height).Select
    With Selection
        .Characters.Text = ButtonName
        .OnAction = Macro
        .Name = ButtonName & Rng
    End With
End Sub

Sub LetsCreateAButton()
    CreateButton("Example", Range("A1"), "RunMacro")
End Sub
```

Each button will run the same macro that will act only in the row of the clicked button, so I'm using the code below to get the row of the clicked button:

```
ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Row
```

But sometimes I get the number of the current row, sometimes I get the number of the row of the first button in the column. Anybody knows what is wrong?

Comment: Try this `Buttons.Add(Rng.Left + 0.1, Rng.Top + 0.1, Rng.Width - 0.2, Rng.Height - 0.2)`

Comment: Very likely that the button has been moved by a very small amount? Since you have the object name relates to the Range, why not utilize it (either use it to report the row or to move it back to where it should be before getting the Row)?

Comment: Maybe you should consider including the row number in the button's name when creating it. I think it would be the most reliable way to get the row of a button later.

Comment: Setting the name of the button as the row number solved this issue. Thank you @mielk and thank you all that answered.